# How do I keep the javascript of my Phonegap application running minimized on android?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

Developed a application using android Phonegap Build and what happens: when minimized, the app is paused ( freezes Apparently javascript ). To solve the problem , I tested the BackgroundMode plugin, but still the same thing. In the app there is an event that begins when an animation reaches a specific frame, but this does not occur when the application is minimized. Well, this is my biggest problem .

Part of the following code :

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function ()
    {
        window["myphonegap"] = true;

        // Create new runtime using the c2canvas
        cr_createRuntime("c2canvas");

        document.addEventListener("pause", function() {
            cr_setSuspended(false);
            cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.enable();
        }, true);

        document.addEventListener("resume", function() {
            cr_setSuspended(false);
            cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.disable();
        }, true);

        document.addEventListener("backbutton", function() {
            cr_setSuspended(false);
        }, true);
    }, true);
```

Comment: What the event is that begin when animation reaches a specific frame? If you can explain it. If that event is causing issues then can not use detect background/minimized event and just remove/unbid the event before happening or something similar with animation etc.

Comment: @AAhad When the animation or the watch arrives in a specific frame or specific time, the event begins (plays an audio in this event ) .
It's strange , in some phones that I tested went well . But not in others . In all tablets tested worked.
I noticed that when I open the app again ( resume )
the animation is still in the same frame but quickly , the app updates the animation and he returns to the frame it should be.